# how to add multiple triggers in a class

Tags: trigger

Im new in using salesforce, I have created multiple triggers with different objects. can I make them compile in one clasS? or I have to set them as is. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

- Each trigger is a compilable unit. They can't be aggregated into a larger file.
- Each trigger applies to one and only one Sobject
- You can have multiple triggers per Sobject but this is not best practice as order of execution is not guaranteed.
- Triggers can invoke methods in classes (static or instance). Classes indirectly invoke triggers by doing DML.

There are many resources on best practice trigger writing. A simple Google will find them. But first and foremost is to bulkify them.  Each trigger needs to be designed to handle up to 200 records of its Sobject (as that is the default trigger set size).

If you plan on writing many triggers over time, investing in learning a trigger framework is well worth doing. It will force you to bulkify. A place to get started is [this article on best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices).

Advanced Apex users should consider Andy Fawcett's [Force.Com Enterprise Architecture and Separation of Concerns](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns)

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you correctly, let me explain here:
 Your Question is:
-> Can I invoke multiple triggers from the same class?
Ans: Yes, Trigger is the snippet of code which executes after any DML operation is happen to that object. So, If you perform multiple DML's on the same or different objects then the corresponding trigger gets executed. 
Some more info: Try to stick to the rule that One Trigger per Object.
This will help you in adding functionality to the trigger in less time. From the trigger you can distinguish different trigger events using the [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm). Also create different method for different events in the trigger handler class.

Answer (score 0):

Every trigger belongs to only one standard/custom object, so the answer is no.

You can have multiple triggers (classes) for a standard/custom object in particular. However as best practices, you should have all of them in only one trigger. This will bring you benefits like easier maintenance and more important is that if you have different triggers (classes), the execution order might not be always the same and this will have as a consequence that your trigger's logic might have conflicts with another trigger of the same object.

I Hope it helps you.